# Calculate $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \displaystyle\binom{n}{k} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-k}k^l}{l!}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove that for all $0 \leq l \leq n$, $$ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \displaystyle\binom{n}{k} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-k}k^l}{l!} = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } l<n \\ 1 \text{ if } l=n \end{cases}$$

I know that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \displaystyle\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k} = 0$
I tried to use summation by parts(Abel lemma) but I wasn't able to conclude.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Proof by inference?

Comment: I'm confused, either it's $l^k$ in the question or $(n-k)^l$ in the comment, right?

Comment: Edit of previous comment:  This can be rewritten as $$\sum(−1)^k\binom nk (n−k)^l=\begin{cases}0&0\leq l<n\\n!&l=n\end{cases}$$
and the left side can be seen as the number of functions $\{1,2,…,l\}\to\{1,…,n\}$ that are onto, using inclusion-exclusion

Comment: Specifically, if $A$ is the set of all functions $f:\{1,\dots,l\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$  and $A_i$ is the set of all such functions which don't have $i$ in the image, then the set of onto maps is $A\setminus(A_1\cup \cdots\cup A_n),$ and count that set using inclusion-exclusion.